# Missing permissions for changing server nickname - Discord bot

Tags: php, discord

I'm attempting to modify the server nickname using Discord's API with PHP's cURL. However, I'm encountering a permission issue despite the bot having administrative privileges and the highest role on the server.

So, I wanted to add a feature where you could change the bot's nickname for the server, but it keeps saying i'm missing permissions.

My site has two scopes for logging in:

- identity
- guild

I am not sure if I need to add more.
My bot has enabled all Privileged Gateway Intents.

Error: Failed to change bot name. Code: 403string(49) "{"message": "Missing Permissions", "code": 50013}".

I can't exactly figure out what the problem is.
It fetches all of the data correctly,
I tried resetting my bot token, but that didn't make any change.
I have tried editing the permissions of the bot, but that didn't help either.
The bot is an administrator, has the highest role with all permissions, including MANAGE_NICKNAMES. But somehow, it still doesn't allow me to change the nickname.
I also whether the guild_id and the bot_id were correct, and they indeed were.
I am clueless. What do I have to do?

PHP:

```php
   $bot_token = '...'; // Only for this article
   $guild_id = $_GET['guild_id'];

  if (!empty($_POST['bot_name'])) {
      $botName = $_POST['bot_name'];
      $ch = curl_init("https://discord.com/api/v10/users/@me");
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
          'Authorization: Bot ' . $bot_token,
          'Content-Type: application/json',
          'User-Agent: YourBotName/1.0',
      ]);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      $bot_info_response = curl_exec($ch);
      curl_close($ch);
      $bot_info = json_decode($bot_info_response, true);
      $bot_id = $bot_info['id'];
      $change_nickname_url = "https://discord.com/api/v10/guilds/{$guild_id}/members/{$bot_id}";
      $data = [
          'nick' => $botName,
      ];

      $ch = curl_init($change_nickname_url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
          'Authorization: Bot ' . $bot_token,
          'Content-Type: application/json',
          'User-Agent: Sentinel/1.0', 
      ]);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PATCH');
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      $change_nickname_response = curl_exec($ch);

      if ($change_nickname_response === false) {
          echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
      } else {
          $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
          if ($http_code === 200) {
              echo 'Bot name changed successfully.';
          } else {
              echo 'Failed to change bot name. Code: ' . $http_code;
              var_dump($change_nickname_response); 
          }
      }

      curl_close($ch);
  } else {
      $botName = null;
  }
```

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Can you please point to the documentation of the specific endpoint, that you are basing this on?

Comment: https://discord.com/api/v10/guilds/{$guild_id}/members/{$bot_id}

Comment: Right, what API endpoint URL you are using, I can see myself in the above code. I asked for the _documentation_ you are basing this on.

Comment: the discord developer documentation, 
https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro

Comment: _"modify the server nickname"_ - the _exact_ part of the documentation where that is explained is what I meant.

Comment: I already fixed the problem, I used the wrong API link. Thank you for your time anyway! Issue:
I used this link:
Modify Guild Member
PATCH/guilds/{guild.id}/members/{user.id}

Instead of this link:
Modify Current Member
PATCH/guilds/{guild.id}/members/@me